# Pandas rolling count over multiple columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a tennis dataset which has player 1 and player 2, sometimes a player is player 1 and sometimes they are player 2. The dataset also shows whether the player won or lost. With p1_win and p2_win, if the player won they receive a 1 and if they lose they receive a 0.

This is what I currently have

| p1_name | p2_name | p1_win | p2_win |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nadal | Murray | 1 | 0 |
| Murray | Nadal | 0 | 1 |
| Murray | Nadal | 0 | 1 |

I would like to have a rolling count of how many games the player has won before the start of the match, like below

| p1_name | p2_name | p1_win | p2_win | p1_totalwins | p2_totalwins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nadal | Murray | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Murray | Nadal | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Murray | Nadal | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

This is the current code I have:

```
df_list = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    tmp = df[["match_id", f"p{i}_name", f"p{i}_win"]].copy()
    tmp.columns = ["match_id", "player", "score"]
    df_list.append(tmp)
df_long = pd.concat(df_list)
rolling_scores = df_long.sort_values("match_id").groupby("player")["score"].cumsum().cumcount().reset_index()
rolling_scores["score"] = rolling_scores.groupby("player")["score"].shift(1).values
for i in range(1, 3):
    tmp = rolling_scores.copy()
    tmp.columns = [f"p{i}_name", "match_id", f"p{i}_total_wins"]
    df = df.merge(tmp, on=["match_id", f"p{i}_name"], how="left")
```

Comment: what do you mean "if the player won they receive a 1 and if they lose they receive a **2**"? Why 2?

Comment: Sorry that should've been a 0, I have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p1_win, p2_win columns are different across your two tables btw.

There are many ways to solve your problem. The simplest I could come up with that requires the fewest operations is shown below. This method requires maintaining external state outside of your dataframe.

```
external_state_dic = {}


def player_win_cumsum(row):
    p1 = row["p1_name"]
    p2 = row["p2_name"]
    p1_wins = external_state_dic.get(p1, 0)
    p2_wins = external_state_dic.get(p2, 0)
    external_state_dic[p1] = p1_wins + row["p1_win"]
    external_state_dic[p2] = p2_wins + row["p2_win"]

    return p1_wins, p2_wins


df["p1_totalwins"], df["p2_totalwins"] = zip(*df.apply(player_win_cumsum, axis=1))
```

Comment: That was worked perfect. thank you for the help :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. If this answer worked then please "Accept" it as the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Just another one, would you know how to work out win percentage and also win percentage in i.e. last 5 games?

Comment: `external_state_dic`, in the example above, has player name as the key and wins as the value. In order to get win percentage, value should be a tuple of (wins, matches). In order to get win percentage in last 5 games, then value should be a queue of last 5 games for that player.